# Javascript port access

Tags: javascript, networking

Can javascript access the system ports ?
If yes, is it possible to write a server (TCP/UDP in C) to which data can be send from javascript ?

Comment: Javascript running in a web-browser, or running e.g. [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) or similar?

Comment: Javascript running in a web-browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that you're not asking for [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

You can write WebSocket server in C and connect your JavaScript to it. There are already plenty of implementations so you don't have to write it yourself.

When you start your server and bind it to specific host name and port you can connect from your JavaScript by:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://hostname:port');
ws.onopen = function () {
   console.log('Connected');
};
ws.onmessage = function () {
   console.log('New message...');
};
ws.send('Some message...');
```

For example, here is one http://code.google.com/p/cwebsocket/.

As far as I know WebSocket is over TCP.

One more option is to create HTTP server use AJAX with or without long polling.

Comment: writing server is part of the project, so can't use an external server. Did they code the server using the normal TCP-server functions like : socket(), bind(), listen(), send() and receive() ??

Comment: Yes, you can do it in that way. You just have to parse HTTP requests because the WebSocket handshake is over HTTP. Here is the specification of the protocol for your ease http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455

Comment: Yes, JavaScript is the easiest part. The server implementation will be more complex.

Comment: sock_desc=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
server.sin_family=AF_INET; <br/>
server.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); <br/>
server.sin_port=3001; <br/> Now will i be able to receive msg from that js client ??

Comment: No, you won't see the specification of websockets above. First you need http server which handles upgrade requests.

Comment: Upgrade from HTTP to WebSocket.

Comment: does that mean i have to write a C server to handle Websockets ??

Comment: Not necessary you can write it to handle only HTTP requests. This will be the easiest way to create communication between C server and web-browser JavaScript.

Comment: when i am trying to send a "hello" from js to C-server, the HTTP protocol adds more data (headers) along with "hello". Now it sends it (headers + "hello") to port 3001. So if my C-server is listening to 3001 , will i receive the "headers" attached ?? but i am not able to :(

Comment: Using HTTP you would have simplex connection only browser -> C server. For duplex you need WebSocket. Please, read the manuals I've sent you.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "system ports"? Serial ports? AGP ports? Rewrites of an application in a different programming language? There is no such term as "system ports" in general usage. You seem to be referring to sockets.

In which case....

Sort of. You can get a connection to any TCP port using javascript - but you will only be able to communicate over that port using HTTP. It is possible to tunnel communications via websockets - however this requires a proxy at the server end to connect to [a conventional server](https://github.com/kumina/wsproxy/blob/master/wsproxy.c). TCP is a stream protocol but websockets are message oriented.

If you're implementing your own server from scratch, then it's a lot easier to build on top of something which already understands about websockets (such as node.js).

You can't use UDP (other than DNS lookups as a by-product of establishing TCP connections).

Comment: all i want is to send a string from javascript to a socket-port (say 3001) and receive it by the server (which i have to code) which is listening to port 3001. So is it possible ??

Comment: Yes - but you need to implement an HTTP stack (or use an existing one) unless you use a websocket proxy.